# How to connect styles to page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried to do this using:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/css.css'); }}
```

But I get error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'
```

Maybe I should connect extension?

Comment: just remove the semicolon (;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon and it should work.